How to use password with `@` in connection string in YugabyteDB?
How do you escape a password that contains “@“ in connection string?
When I ssh to the pod and echo the ENV it outputs the correct password, but the app can’t access the DB. It throws incorrect password.
I find it very strange.

You can replace@ by %40 (40 is the ascii for @). Example:
create user fr password 'p@ss';
psql -d postgres://fr:p%40ss@eu-west-1.7929e...

